# Inserting another column to a data frame and incrementing its value per row

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
 head(df,10)
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7    V8    V9  V10
3  36.4 13.1 13.9 36.6 9.26 57.9 28.0 34.96 26049 3492
4  31.1 11.2 12.6 45.1 7.81 48.8 25.9 37.85 17515 2754
5  33.2 13.4 13.2 40.3 8.69 54.3 26.9 35.67 23510 3265
6  34.0 12.8 13.7 39.4 8.77 54.8 26.5 35.19 25151 3305
7  32.7 12.4 13.6 41.3 8.49 53.0 25.9 35.97 25214 3201
8  33.4 13.7 12.5 40.3 8.76 54.7 27.1 36.50 23943 3391
9  35.2 13.8 13.5 37.5 9.20 57.5 27.8 33.08 25647 3385
10 34.6 14.9 14.9 35.6 9.35 58.4 27.8 35.81 27324 3790
11 30.4 13.3 13.0 43.3 8.29 51.8 24.9 38.31 25178 2881
12 32.0 13.3 14.0 40.7 8.58 53.6 26.1 35.97 25677 3162
```

I have DateTime is this:

```
DateTime<-Sys.time()
```

I would like to insert another column this df and increment the DateTime value by 30 seconds for each row.

Im doing this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 df[1,]$DateTime<-DateTime
 DateTime<-DateTime+30
}
```

This loop is not doing what Im trying to do. Any help is greatly appreicated.

Comment: @Arun, each row DateTime field need to be incremented by 30. For example, 1st row's DateTime will be Sys.time, 2nd row will be Sys.time+30, 3rd row will be Sys.time+30+30

Comment: Yes, this works: `df$DateTime <- Sys.time() + 30 * (seq_len(nrow(df))-1)`
`

Comment: that worked, you know much cool functions. thank you

Comment: you can write this as an answer and mark as answered.

Comment: @Arun, I need to ask you another question. Besides RCurl, do you know any other way to sftp get files from remote sftp site. Rcurl seems to be haning sometimes for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$DateTime <- Sys.time() + 30 * (seq_len(nrow(df))-1)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation why it works like this way? Code-only answers are discouraged here.

Comment: Interesting comment. This is the first I have ever heard that claim. The Poster obviously knows what Sys.time() returns and is the one that requested that the comment be posted as an answer, so presumably understood that in R adding a scalar (or more accurately a length one vector) to a length-n vector would return a length-n vector. Are you suggesting we need to read the help page for `seq` to him as well?

Comment: @DWin - being fare if you liked the answer you could have given it a credit :-)

Comment: SO is a no-fare zone, but I am trying to be fair. So why didn't you give the upvote?